# Laravel 5.5 Update a checkbox of many to many relationship model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, many-to-many

I have a **many to many** relationship where I had a two models that belongsToMany to each other.

So I would like to update the pivot table but first I want to know if the two models are already existing on this pivot tables.

So here is the definition of my relationship in my two models below:

**AnalysisRequest model**

```
public function request_methods()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Methodologies')->withTimestamps();;
        }
```

and in my other model: **Methodologies model**

```
public function methods_requested()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\AnalysisRequest')->withTimestamps();;
    }
```

So this two models has their own pivot table with all their **ID** attached. Now what I want to happen is when the two models has existing attached models to each other I want the checkbox to be checked on the view which I couldn't achieve.

Here is the **pivot model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Eloquent as Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class AnalysisRequestMethodologies extends Model
{

        public $table = 'analysis_request_methodologies';

        public $fillable = [
            'analysis_request_id',
            'methodologies_id',
        ];

        /**
         * The attributes that should be casted to native types.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $casts = [
            'analysis_request_id' => 'integer',
            'methodologies_id' => 'integer',
        ];

        /**
         * Validation rules
         *
         * @var array
         */
        public static $rules = [
            'analysis_request_id' => 'required|unique_with:analysis_request_methodologies,methodologies_id',
            'methodologies_id' => 'required',
        ];
}
```

Here is my code **controller** below:

```
 public function edit($id)
{
    $analysis_request = $this->analysisrequestRepository->findWithoutFail($id);

    $checkeds = AnalysisRequest::find($id)->request_methods()->pluck('id');

    return view('encoder-dashboard.analysis-request-methods.create', compact('analysis_request', 'checkeds'));
}
```

And in my **view**

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-12">
    @forelse($analysis_request->category->methodology as $method)
    <label>
        <?php $checked = in_array($method->id, $checkeds) ? true : false; ?>
        {{ Form::checkbox('methodologies_id[]', $method->id) }}
        {{ $method->name }} with the lead time of {{ $method->lead_time }} and the DOH standard of {{ $method->doh_standard }}
    </label>
    @empty
        <h3>The category you selected has no method yet</h3>
    @endforelse
</div>
```

Anothere reference of [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20179473/many-to-many-eloquent-relationship-update-with-laravel-form-model-binding-chec) that can be related to my question.

I have an error in my **view** that sais:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in field list is
>   ambiguous (SQL: select `id` from `methodologies` inner join
>   `analysis_request_methodologies` on `methodologies`.`id` =
>   `analysis_request_methodologies`.`methodologies_id` where
>   `analysis_request_methodologies`.`analysis_request_id` = 10)

In the [referenced question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20179473/many-to-many-eloquent-relationship-update-with-laravel-form-model-binding-chec) the solution said I need to use `lists` but it was depreciated in **Laravel 5** I need to use `pluck` instead. But still can't solve the puzzle.

Appreciate if someone could help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to use `->pluck('methodologies.id');`?
Like shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/40636391

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assumed that your related table name is `methodologies`, so your query should be like below

```
$checkeds = AnalysisRequest::find($id)->request_methods()->pluck('methodologies.id');
```

You have to specify the table name because eloquent creating a query and joining tables when you say that `request_methods()` mysql should know which table is id belongs to

Comment: I tried it but now I have an error that sais `in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given`

Comment: Have fixed it using `toArray()` method thank you so much!

Comment: @jaaayz use toArray() method, pluck returns collection

Comment: Thanks to you :))